# Error "Server terminated early with status 1" after try perform selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Actually using selenium 2.53.2, nodeJS v5.12.0 and chromedriver 2.24.1 I'm trying to perform my tests locally but getting the error `Server terminated early with status 1`

[image]

Anyone to help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

I solved my problem uninstalling chromedriver package using `npm uninstall -g chromedriver` and installed again using `npm install -g chromedriver`

Cheers!

Comment: Confirmed this works as well when using Firefox, just uninstall/install the `geckodriver` with `npm`.